# (Vue.js) What am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Hi I have a problem with vue.js when I run it I get 2 Erros saying:  'rechner' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars and 'Vue' is not defined. The Webapp is for listing grades and get the average of it. I am also working with vue routers thats why I exported "Brazil".

Thanks for the help.

````
  <div>
    Brazl
    <!--<script type="application/javascript" src="rechner.js"></script>-->
    <h2>Noten-Calculator</h2>
    <div id="rechner">
      <ul>
        <li v-for="(n,idx) in noten" :key="idx">{{idx+1}}. Note : {{n}}</li>
      </ul>
      <div>
        <label>Neue Note:</label>
        <input type="text" v-model="neueNote" />
        <button v-on:click="addNote()">Ok</button>
      </div>
      <br>
      <div>
        <p>Mein Notendurchschnitt: </p>
        <label>Durchschnitt:</label>
        <input type="text" v-model="calcAvg" />
        <button v-on:click="calcAvg()">Durchschnitt</button>
      </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Brazil",
  props: {}
};
var rechner = new Vue({
    el: '#rechner',
    data: {
      noten: [],
      neueNote: 0,
      avg: 0
    },
    methods: {
      addNote: function () {
        this.noten.push(this.neueNote)
        this.neueNote = 0
      },
      calcAvg: function () {
        let sum = 0;
        //iteriere über alle Noten und zähle zusammen
        for (var i = 0; i < this.noten.length; i++) {
          let zahl = parseInt(this.noten[i]);
          sum = sum + zahl;
        }
        //berechne durchschnitt und gebe aus
        console.log(sum)
        console.log(this.noten.length)
        return sum / this.noten.length;
      }
    }
  })
</script>```
````

Comment: Just a side note, and maybe a personal preference: The programming, coding and markup languages themselves are (simplified statement) in English, and as you are now reaching out for help on a platform that is used worldwide, you maybe want to form a habit of always writing your code in English.

Comment: you initialize the variable `rechner` but never use it, so the no-unused-vars erro is correct. The second thing is, that you doesn't import Vue, so it is undefined

Comment: @pduersteler Alright I will write my code in English next time.

Comment: @JulianS How could I use it?